# How to provision SQS via Terraform when DLQ doesn't yet exist?

Tags: amazon-sqs, terraform

How can a SQS-queue be provisioned to specify a policy like `maxReceiveCount` for its dead letter queue, when neither the queue nor the dead letter queue exist?

The [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/sqs_queue.html#example-usage) suggests its possible:

```
resource "aws_sqs_queue" "terraform_queue" {
  # ...
  redrive_policy = "{\"deadLetterTargetArn\":\"${aws_sqs_queue.terraform_queue_deadletter.arn}\",\"maxReceiveCount\":4}"
}
```

And I'm inclined to think that folks must have given this some thought and gotten it to work before [adding](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/pull/3030) it into the [docs](https://github.com/br0ch0n/terraform/commit/5bdba000823ea2abcfe4eaa0136065d0451be5b9).

Therefore, I'm looking for insights about what I'm missing and what I should do to get around reasonable error messages like this one:

```
unknown resource 'aws_sqs_queue.terraform_queue_deadletter'
referenced in variable aws_sqs_queue.terraform_queue_deadletter.arn
```

Comment: Ahhh nevermind! Jumping from Elastic Beanstalk (EB) into Terraform, I did not realize that EB was provisioning two separate queues then wiring them up on behalf of admins. I thought queue+DLQ provisioning was an atomic action in SQS, if that is not the case then the error makes sense. Just need to provision two queues and wire them up ... got this clue while looking at open source repos: https://github.com/Raymondsquared/Terraform/blob/9dfd8574e45cb86b55b6bdb8771d35bea2935440/example.tf#L13

Comment: It's probably worth self answering this to show other users how Terraform manages dependencies between resources.

Comment: @lf215 just seen this bounty and how it is very closely related to [your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52359343/2291321). Part of me is tempted to close it as a duplicate of your question as the answer is a bit more detailed but I'm concerned that the answer is a little too closely built around the module you are using. Would you prefer to see this explained more here without the use of modules to simplify the answer a little?

Comment: Yes please explain more here

Comment: https://registry.terraform.io/modules/damacus/sqs-with-dlq/aws/latest could be of help!

Answer (score 1):

Jumping from Elastic Beanstalk (EB) into Terraform, I did not realize that EB was provisioning two separate queues then wiring them up on behalf of admins.

I thought queue+DLQ provisioning was an atomic action in SQS, if that is not the case then the error makes sense. Just need to provision two queues and wire them up.

Got this clue while looking at open source repos:
https://github.com/Raymondsquared/Terraform/blob/9dfd8574e45cb86b55b6bdb8771d35bea2935440/example.tf#L13